# 500 Internal Server Error and blank page after migrating PHP project from 5.6 to 7.3

Tags: php, netbeans, migration

I need to migrate a PHP project from 5.6 to 7.3.

I'm using XAMPP locally for mysql module and Apache module. I also needed to update XAMPP from an older version to XAMPP for Windows 7.3.15 which has 7.3 support. Before I did this I backed up the database and the htdocs file with my project files. I also updated NetBeans to the latest version since the one I had didn't support 7.3.

After installing the new version of XAMMP I copied the htdocs project folder back in the same directory and restored the database(which was easier sais that done because it was pretty big and it kept timing out and I had to meddle with some php.ini configuration settings).

Now I'm trying to open the index.php page but I'm getting the 500 Internal Server Error. Checked the apache error logs and php error logs and I couldn't find anything.

There might be a problem with the XAMMP installation because the control panel still says 3.2.4 and the http://localhost/dashboard/ greets me with Welcome to XAMPP for Windows 5.6.31.

Oh, and the phpmyadmin page works fine.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? You could grep your code for `mysql_` that is one known issue that would produce this behavior.

Comment: I've checked both the apache and the PHP server logs and they contain no errors. Error reporting is enabled. Not sure about the grep situation since I am using Windows

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a PHP issue than NetBeans. Anyway, you can try adding the following lines at the beginning of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", true);
```

Then try to reload the page, you should see the exact error and the line number.

Comment: Tried that but I still don't get anything, only a 500 chrome error in the console window